# How to Swap Boxes in gridview builder randomly in Flutter Dart Language...?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to swap the boxes each time and place a specific digit in one box. Basically I have 4 Boxes and I want to swap then randomly each time.

Any Ideas?

```
var gridView = new GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 4,
        gridDelegate:
            new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          int rand = random.nextInt(20);
          return new GestureDetector(
            child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  //    int t = i;
                  // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  //   builder: (context) => Table2(t),
                  // )
                  // );
                },
```

Comment: why don't you randomize the data? just shuffle your list and rebuild the grid widget

Comment: There is a package that nearly does what you want [here](https://pub.dev/packages/local_hero). You can perhaps check the source code and improve it to do the swapping randomly.